# How to Release to the App Store as an Individual

Tags: ios, appstore

I've written an iOS app, and I'd like to release it on to the App Store. I'm an individual so it's not being released via a company or anything, just me.

Is it typical to just release a free app under your own name? If so, what would be appropriate copyright information to submit?

Comment: The copyright would be owned by you.

Comment: For anyone voting to close - why? This is very much on-topic. Not only is it a freelancing and business concern, it's also related to software distribution, which affects any developer trying to distribute their software.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm voting off topic, because this seems to be a basic support question to ask Apple directly in its current state.

Comment: @Ryathal I can understand Apple (or any other app market) providing technical support, I don't think they would explain various options and trade-offs that exist with each one.

Comment: Apologies if this isn't the right place to ask - for what it's worth I checked several other Stack Exchange sites, and related questions on this one, and it appeared to fit in with those.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I'm starting to see that Freelancing and Business Concerns is casting a very wide net.

Comment: This question is being discussed in our [Meta site](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/do-we-accept-questions-about-the-intricacies-of-apples-distribution-process), if you have an opinion on whether it's on or off topic please post it there.

Comment: Truthfully, Apple should have something publicly to say about this, but they don't, probably because they're not in the business of dispensing legal advice.  Neither are we.

Comment: You're not asking about providing a custom EULA, are you? If so, this section of the iTunes Connect Developer Guide would be of interest: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW47. Beyond that, I can't think of any copyright-related documentation that you submit to Apple in the account registration process or afterward.

Comment: The copyright question is one for your lawyer (or perhaps your own reading of the law IF you trust that), and depends on who wrote the app, derivations, job or contractual obligations, and etc.  Many independent developers seem to just use their own name, but that isn't legal advice (covering your potential liabilities, and etc.)

Comment: @hotpaw2 I went with submitting under my own name in the end

Answer (score 2):

I'm an individual that has an app on the App Store, you can of course submit it as individual (Apple has different developer accounts for companies & "solo programmers").

For sure the copyright of the material is yours, just add a simple message (not really needed, indeed) like "© 2012 John Smith" somewhere in your app to be sure.

Please also consider that anybody can copy your material and/or ideas on the App Store, lots of people clones successful apps there. If your idea is so valuable consider also to apply for a registered trademark or similar.

**P.S.**
Your app is free as you said, but if you're trying to get some money from that just be sure to check what taxes you have to pay in your country.

Answer (score 1):

It is typical to release free/paid apps on AppStore as individual as you can see there are many individual submit apps in the AppStore. The verification process of registering or upgrading as organisation is long. Sometime we release app as individual and then upgrade to organisation because of this.

For the copyright, it is ok to set copyright as others in `Version information` in `iTunes Connect`,e.g., You created an account with Thomas Owen but you fill in the copyright as Owen Inc. The same could be apply in the launch screen or other information in you apps.